# Как сделать правильное обновление контента на странице

Tags: php, ajax

Каким образом будет правильнее всего сделать автоматическое обновление контента на странице (без перезагрузки) ?
Задача в том что нужно обновлять не несколько блоков. Замена всего html не подходит, занимает много ресурсов.
Для каждого блока делать свой запрос тоже не вариант, так как блоков более 5, нагрузка будет. А что если будет открыто несколько вкладок страницы - запросы будут идти с нескольких вкладок сразу...

Как сделать правильно и с минимальным потребление ресурсов.

Comment: Почему то никто не предложил WebSocket использовать =) что странно =)

Answer (score 1):

1. 5 реквестов - далеко не сильно страшно.
2. Можно сделать отдельный скрипт для проверки наличия обновлений, и уже потом, при необходимости, их грузить
3. Можно проверять, активна ли вкладка. Но, тут уже надо смотреть на задачу. Далеко не везде это приемлемо
4. Заменять "весь html" тоже не нужно. С тем же успехом можно было просто вкладку обновить. Работать нужно с конкретными блоками

Answer (score 0):

На серверной стороне делаете массив с содержимым для каждого блока, и кодируете его в json. Потом этот json возвращается вам в тот документ, откуда вы делаете ajax запрос. Потом вы уже можете распихать все по отдельным блокам на странице.

Comment: может есть какие-то практические примеры подобной реализации?

Comment: Вставьте свой код примерный, я вам набросаю как его переделать.